# Selenium: test freezes when executing javascript command "return document.readyState"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

*Selenium 2.47.1. Firefox 39.0. Java 1.8*

Sometimes during the test when new page is opened, spinner near the favicon is displayed infinitely (it's bug of the tested application).

I use method that waits for page to load or refresh the page, if page isn't loaded after a minute.

In most cases page is loaded after *10-15 seconds* and the method isn't neccessary. In other cases this method runs successfully and page refreshes after a minute.

But sometimes (when the spinner doesn't disappear) test freezes when executing this command

```
((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return document['readyState'] ? 'complete' == document.readyState : true")
```

Here is the full method for waiting

```
public void waitForPageToLoad(){
  started = System.currentTimeMillis();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Long.parseLong(getTimeoutForPageLoad()));
  try {
      wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
          public Boolean apply(final WebDriver d) {
              if (!(d instanceof JavascriptExecutor)) {
                  return true;
              }
              Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return document['readyState'] ? 'complete' == document.readyState : true");
              if (result != null && result instanceof Boolean && (Boolean) result) {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (now - started > Long.parseLong(getTimeoutForPageLoad())) {
                  return true;
                }else {
                  started = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
              }
              return false;
          }
      });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    refresh();
    waitForPageToLoad();
  }
}
```

Comment: That javascript look awfully complicated. Any chance `boolean result = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return document.readyState == 'complete'");` works?

Comment: @ParkerBeck Unfortunately no. Test hangs in the same place. Also the same issue was reproducible when i've used method click() from the org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement. It contains the following command: execute("clickElement", ImmutableMap.of("id", this.id)). When i use such click, test can freeze if the spinner doesn't disappear. The solution was to use such command executeScript("arguments[0].click();", getElement());

Answer (score 0):

There only one solution i've found: add thread that waits for 50 seconds and refreshes the page if the waitForPageToLoad() freezes

```
class NewThread extends Thread {
Thread thread;
boolean isRunning = true;

NewThread() {
  thread = new Thread(this, "new thread");
  System.out.println("2nd thread is created " + thread);
  thread.start();
}

public void setIsRunning(boolean isRunning){
  this.isRunning = isRunning;
}

public boolean getIsRunning(){
  return isRunning;
}

public void run() {
  try {
      Thread.sleep(50000);
    if (getIsRunning()) {
      Logger.getInstance().info("refresh using thread");
      Browser.getInstance().refresh();
      waitForPageToLoad();
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("2nd thread is interrupted");
  }
  System.out.println("2nd thread is ended");
}
}

public void waitForPageToLoad(){
NewThread thread1 = new NewThread();
  Logger.getInstance().info("waitForPageToLoad started");
  started = System.currentTimeMillis();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Long.parseLong(getTimeoutForPageLoad()));
  try {
      wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
          public Boolean apply(final WebDriver d) {
              if (!(d instanceof JavascriptExecutor)) {
                  return true;
              }
              Object result = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return document.readyState == 'complete'");
              if (result != null && result instanceof Boolean && (Boolean) result) {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (now - started > Long.parseLong(getTimeoutForPageLoad())) {
                  return true;
                }else {
                  started = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
              }
              return false;
          }
      });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    refresh();
    waitForPageToLoad();
  }
  Logger.getInstance().info("waitForPageToLoad ended");
thread1.setIsRunning(false);
}
```